# Porque no me accede a la actividad- AndroidStudio

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de tipo calendario para un reto,cuando lo probé me di cuenta de que no me accedía como debería a la actividad que se encargaría de mostrar los eventos de un día. Os pongo el código de la actividad principal y del de ver los eventos de un día, creo que el error esta cuando creo un objeto Bundle para recoger los datos aunque yo lo veo bien. Gracias por vuestra ayuda.
MainActivity:

```
package com.alumno.calendario;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CalendarView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  
CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener{


private CalendarView calendarview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    calendarview= findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    calendarview.setOnDateChangeListener(this);
}
// este método saltara cuando se cambie las fechas en el calendario
@Override
public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    CharSequence [] items = new CharSequence[3]; //contenerá las opciones 
que podrá escoger el usuario
    items[0]= "Agregar eventos";
    items[1]="Ver eventos";
    items[2]="Cancelar";

    final int dia,mes,anio;
    dia=i;
    mes=i1+1;// esto es por que el més empieza en cero y de esta manera se 
evita eso
    anio=i2;


    //Le ponemos título a la alerta y le ponemos las opciones más un 
escuchador de cuando presione dichas opciones
    builder.setTitle("Seleccione una opción")
        .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                //comparamos la opción seleccionada
                if (i==0){
                    //actividad agregar eventos
                    Intent intent=new Intent( getApplication(), 
AddActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("dia",dia);
                    bundle.putInt("mes",mes);
                    bundle.putInt("anio",anio);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else if (i==1){
                    //ver actividad eventos
                    Intent intent=new Intent( getApplication(), ViewEventsActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("dia",dia);
                    bundle.putInt("mes",mes);
                    bundle.putInt("anio",anio);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    //selecciona cancelar y salimos del método
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

    AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

ViewEventsActivity:

```
package com.alumno.calendario;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ViewEventsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener{

//Declaramos un array el cual uaremos para leer los datos de la base de 
datos
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String >arrayAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_events);

    listView=findViewById(R.id.ltvListaEventos);
    //nos sirve para cuando se mantiene presionado un item en la lista y 
    para borrar elementos
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int dia=0,mes=0,anio=0;
    dia= bundle.getInt("dia");
    mes= bundle.getInt("mes");
    anio= bundle.getInt("anio");

    //metemos los valores en un String para poder validar los datos en la 
    BBDD
    String cadena= dia+ " - " +mes+ " - " +anio;

    //conectamos a nuestra BBDD en modo lectura
    BDSQLite bd= new BDSQLite(getApplicationContext(),"Agenda",null,1);
    db = bd.getReadableDatabase();//modo lectura

    String sql=" select * from eventos  where fechaDesde= '"+ cadena+"'";
    //delcaramos una variable de tipod Cursor que nos servira para guardar 
    los registros que nos devuelva la consulta
    Cursor c;
    //declaramos variables temporales para almacenar los datos temporalmente
    String nombre, fechadesde,fechahasta,descripcion,ubicacion;
    try{
        //los registros que nos devuelva los guardamos  en c
        c= db.rawQuery(sql,null);
        //instanciamos el arrayAdapter
        arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        //comparamos que haya datos para leer
        if(c.moveToNext()){
            do{
                nombre=c.getString(1);
                ubicacion=c.getString(2);
                fechadesde=c.getString(3);
                fechahasta=c.getString(5);
                descripcion=c.getString(7);

                arrayAdapter.add(nombre+", "+ubicacion+", "+fechadesde+", 
"+fechahasta+", "+descripcion);
            }while (c.moveToNext());
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }else{
            //si no hay datos en el cursor no mostramos la interfaz
            this.finish();
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Error"+e.getMessage(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //si ocurre algun error cierra la interfaz
        this.finish();
    }

}

private void eliminar(String dato){
    String[]datos=dato.split(", ");

    String sql="Delete from eventos where nombreEvento='"+datos[0]+"' and 
ubicacion='"+datos[1]+"' and fechadesde='"+datos[2]+"' and 
fechahasta='"+datos[3]+"' and descripcion='"+datos[4]+"'";
    try {
        arrayAdapter.remove(dato);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        db.execSQL(sql);
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Evento eliminado", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Error"+e.getMessage(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, 
int position, long id) {
    //agregamos un dialogo para que el usuario pueda eliminar el evento
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[1];
    items[0]="Eliminar eventos";
    items[1]="Cancelar";
    builder.setTitle("Eliminar evento")
            .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        //eliminar evento
                        //le pasamos el dato que selecciona el usuario

eliminar(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                    }
                }
            });
    AlertDialog dialog =builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    return false;
}
}
```

---

Comment: Hola, podrias ser un poco mas especifico con esto de "no me accedía como debería a la actividad". La app se cierra? hay un crash? no recibe algun parmetro? se muestra roto el layout? si hay un crash por favor sube ademas toda la informacion del error que encuentres en el logcat

Comment: no hay crash ni nada simplemente no me accede, por mucho que seleccione la opción no pasa nada pero para las demás si funciona. Lo siento si me e expresado mal.

Comment: El codigo parece estar correcto, asegurate de tener el activity declarado en el manifest y agrega un log para estar seguro del valor de i en el onClick

Comment: Cuando haces Intent intent=new Intent( getApplication(), 
AddActivity.class); utiliza getApplicationContext() o this dependiendo donde estés como te ha dicho el compañero en la respuesta. Con eso solucionas el tema del intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar el `Intent`, usa como contexto `getApplicationContext()` o `ViewEventsActivity.this` en lugar de `getApplication()` lo cual no es correcto:

```
        ...
        ...
        }else if (i==1){
            //ver actividad eventos
            Intent intent=new Intent( getApplicationContext(), ViewEventsActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("dia",dia);
            bundle.putInt("mes",mes);
            bundle.putInt("anio",anio);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
        ...
        ...
```